# How do i delete an image after moving it in pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame, grid

I am trying to delete the previous image after moving. This is the code of how i am moving the image (unit0

```
def Move(x, y):
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            Background.blit(RedInfantry,(-x*64, 0))
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            Background.blit(RedInfantry,(x*64, 0))
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            Background.blit(RedInfantry,(0, -y*64))
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            Background.blit(RedInfantry,(0, y*64))
```

The starting place is in the top left corner instead of where the image is . Furthermore i don't know how to delete the previous image once it has been moved. If i move twice in different directions it creates to separate images instead of deleting the last one.
[image: This is the image when the down and right button is pressed]

How can i delete the previous image?

Comment: The simplest way is to just redraw the background / fill the screen surface every frame.

Comment: Wouldnt that move the image back to its original space?

Comment: You can't "move" or "delete" an image. Once you blit a Surface onto another (e.g. a Surface created from an image file onto the screen Surface), it's there forever, until you draw/blit something on top.

Answer (score 0):

Base on one of your previous questions ([Image loading using pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60617748/image-loading-using-pygame)), you have to change the position of the image in the grid:

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

    new_x, new_y = x, y
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        new_x -= 1
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        new_x += 1
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        new_y -= 1
    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        new_x += 1

    grid[new_x][new_y] = grid[x][y]
    grid[x][y] = None
```

Of course you have to redraw the entire scene (the grid and the images) in every frame.
(Like in the answer to [Image loading using pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60617748/image-loading-using-pygame))

Comment: This has stopped the image from moving at all, originally it moved from the top Left corner, is there a way to select the image that i want to move

Comment: No, i'm just trying to get the image to move for now, because from the code i have posted i have the problem of it moving but leaving an image in each place of where it has moved. I am trying to delete the previous image after i move it.

Comment: ok, thank you i will try to be more clear and specific when posting the questions